# How to add interaction term in Python sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

If I have independent variables [x1, x2, x3]
If I fit linear regression in sklearn 
it will give me something like this:

```
y = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + intercept
```

Polynomial regression with poly =2 
will give me something like

```
y = a*x1^2 + b*x1*x2 ......
```

I don't want to have terms with second degree like x1^2.

how can I get

```
y = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + d*x1*x2
```

if x1 and x2 have high correlation larger than some threshold value j .

Answer (score 39):

For generating polynomial features, I assume you are using [sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures)

There's an argument in the method for considering only the interactions. So, you can write something like:

```
poly = PolynomialFeatures(interaction_only=True,include_bias = False)
poly.fit_transform(X)
```

Now only your interaction terms are considered and higher degrees are omitted. Your new feature space becomes [x1,x2,x3,x1*x2,x1*x3,x2*x3]

You can fit your regression model on top of that

```
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Making your resultant equation `y = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + d*x1*x + e*x2*x3 + f*x3*x1`

**Note:** If you have high dimensional feature space, then this would lead to [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Machine_learning) which might cause problems like overfitting/high variance

Comment: Nice. I would further set `include_bias=False` because the bias column could lead to degeneracy problems with some estimators and `LinearRegression` adds its own intercept term anyway.

Comment: Really helpful answer. It looks like there's a minor typo in your resultant equation: the 4th term on the right hand side should be d*x1*x2.

Answer (score 21):

Use [patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#patsy.dmatrices) to construct a design matrix as follows:

```
y, X = dmatrices('y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2', your_data)
```

Where `your_data` is e.g. a DataFrame with response column `y` and input columns `x1`, `x2` and `x3`.

Then just call the `fit` method of your estimator, e.g. `LinearRegression().fit(X,y)`.

Comment: love the design after lm() in R

Answer (score 12):

If you do `y = a*x1 + b*x2 + c*x3 + intercept` in scikit-learn with linear regression, I assume you do something like that:

```
# x = array with shape (n_samples, n_features)
# y = array with shape (n_samples)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
```

The independent variables *x1*, *x2*, *x3* are the columns of feature matrix `x`, and the coefficients *a*, *b*, *c* are contained in `model.coef_`.

If you want an interaction term, add it to the feature matrix:

```
x = np.c_[x, x[:, 0] * x[:, 1]]
```

Now the first three columns contain the variables, and the following column contain the interaction *x1* * *x2*. After fitting the model you will find that `model.coef_` contains four coefficients *a*, *b*, *c*, *d*.

Note that this will always give you a model with interaction (it can theoretically be 0, though), regardless of the correlation between *x1* and *x2*. Of course, you can measure the correlation beforehand and use it to decide which model to fit.