# Adding interaction effects to a random forest model at scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am running a random forest regression model, but my results are not that great. One person recommended to check interaction effects.

Surprisingly I do not see too many questions about this. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828964/how-to-add-interaction-term-in-python-sklearn) did not help me. I am also not sure how to incorporate to my code [sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html).

My data is very simple:

[image]

My code:

```
# Split data
y = starbucks_log.iloc[:, 0]

# x as all others 
X = starbucks_log.drop('total_amount', axis = 1)

# Set seed for reproducibility
SEED = 1

# Split dataset into 80% train and 20% test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = \
train_test_split(X, y,
test_size = 0.2,
random_state = SEED)

# Instantiate a random forests regressor 'rf' 400 estimators
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 400,
min_samples_leaf = 1,
random_state = SEED)

# Fit 'rf' to the training set
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Predict the test set labels 'y_pred'
y_pred = rf.predict(X_test)
y_pred_train=rf.predict(X_train)
# Evaluate the test set RMSE
rmse_test = MSE(y_test, y_pred)**(1/2)
rmse_train = MSE(y_train, y_pred_train)**(1/2)
# Print the test set RMSE
print('Test set RMSE of rf: {:.5f}'.format(rmse_test))
print('Train set RMSE of rf: {:.5f}'.format(rmse_train))
```

I would like to add all possible interaction effects of `income`, `age`, and `male(gender)`. It would be easier to drop some of them later.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by interaction. Do you mean income*age?? Interaction terms are not generally used in context of random forest as random forest is not parametric model like linear or logistic regression. And there is no assumpttion of independence of variables. You could manually create the interaction term in your dataset and pass it to the model.

Comment: Also refer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201893/how-to-include-an-interaction-term-in-a-random-forest-model. I suggest to post Data Science/ML/Stats related questions in their own groups.

Comment: @QuantumDreamer, yes, income*age. Ok, thanks for this tip. I am new to this.

Comment: Yeah, I do not have problems to make it in R, but I am new to Python

Comment: Please close this question, if you are satisfied with the information from comments. Thank you

Comment: I am not sure how to close a question, based on comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219788/discussion-between-quantum-dreamer-and-anakin-skywalker).